# File code mysteriously turns to a bunch of (0000)

Tags: java, android, windows

An Android-Java source file I was working on (writing code on) in my project on Android Studio has mysteriously turned its code content from actual code to a bunch of zeros; endless rows and 8 columns of "0000".
Like:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
. . . . .
```

This happened after my PC abruptly went off (power issues). (NOTE: My PC runs Windows 10).
I hadn't committed the code I had appended/changed on the file to Git yet - PC went off as I was writing code on this file.

**How can I recover my source code content?**

Re-building, Cleaning the project doesn't work. Restarting the computer doesn't solve this also.
What can I do?

(I had done so much work, I'm already frustrated that the client's deadline is today and it seems like I've lost all work.)

Comment: Had a similar occurance when having a bluescreen while IntelliJ was running. Back then I had nothing to recover my source code with but happily it was a CSS File that was still in my browser cache.
I recommend you to check out the Local history of the file anyway, if you're lucky, your code is still there.

Comment: `... How can I recover my source code content?` Impossible. the data has been overwritten, the file is definetely corrupt. `... What can I do?` Buy an UPS and/or start making backups.

Comment: @Link64 Unfortunately, even Android Studio doesn't recognize any Local History of this file. It's like "Nothing to Show".

Comment: @KlingKlang, I also think there's nothing I can do but re-do the whole work!

Comment: Lessons learned: **1** - Use UPS with non mobile computers (laptops are backed up by a battery - so, a mini-UPS). **2** - Always make backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the file got corrupted and thus unreadable.

The first solution here is to save your work every now and then, as you type.
Second, look into a long term solution, like a UPS or battery cell.